# Handling fatal exceptions thrown in constructor

Tags: java, exception

Let's say I have a class that needs to do some initialization work in its constructor. There is no reason to believe that it will fail, but if it does, the instance (and possibly the application; let's consider these to be two separate cases) will be left in an unusable state with no real hope of recovery within that scope (instance or global).

What is the recommended way to deal with this situation in Java? Rethrowing the exception, wrapped inside a runtime exception, seems like a natural approach, but is there any recommendations or consensus about which exception type to use for such a purpose?

Comment: You can even declare your constructor to throw a checked exception

Comment: So the checked exception is not something that could be cleanly exposed to callers of your constructor?  Like an I/O exception?  `Socket`'s constructors throw checked exceptions, e.g.

Comment: Though sometimes, I can't, or don't want to, throw the exception as-is. For example, when I instantiate a class that makes use of the OpenSAML library, I might not want to decorate the constructor (or a bunch of methods) with `throws org.opensaml.xml.ConfigurationException`, but if that exception does get thrown, trying to continue will just net me other exceptions further down the road.

Comment: I know I can just wrap it up in another exception type, but hence the question; particularly for such general exceptions, is there any sort of best practice for which exception types to expose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something in your constructor throws an exception you could either declare it to throw exceptions itself or maybe wrap them with a more general exception (like an own InstantiateXxxxException).

Generally, you have multiple types of `Throwable` that have a different meaning.
I'd classify them as follows:

- Exception (checked): thrown when state is recoverable or additional handling is needed
- RuntimeException (unchecked): thrown when unexpected exceptions (like NPE) occur, application might still be in a stable state, depends on the handling and the situation. Some frameworks (like EJB) wrap every exception into a RuntimeException (or more commonly subclasses thereof) in order to make a "cleaner" interface.
- Error (unchecked): this is mostly thrown when something extremely bad happens which will destabilize the application or even the JVM (like OutOfMemoryError). In that case the application will normally quit, although you might want to catch them and do some special handling if possible (like writing a log etc.).

Comment: In this particular case at least, I ended up deciding to wrap the exception in a `RuntimeException`. It gives the caller a chance to handle the situation more gracefully if desired, doesn't require me to handle an exception that truly is the exceptional case (if library initialization fails, something is probably wrong with the deployment), and communicates intent in expressing that this is likely not easily recoverable, particularly by the caller. I do believe that's good enough in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on what goes wrong. I mean if it fails because of null values then NullPointerexception and if you come across state which wasn't expected then probably IllegalStateException.

But I would suggest instead of exposing constructor just have a static factory methods which you can name and can handle this kind of scenarios gracefully.
e.g.

```
public class A{
  private A() {}

  private init() { .. }

   public static A getNewInstance() { //  may be parameters if you want
      A a = new A();
      a.init();
  }
}
```

I just gave an example of `init` but you can have other alternatives as well, point is you can have static method to deal with such stuff than constructor, if constructor is handling complex logic.

Comment: Should be `public static A getNewInstance() {` :)

Comment: How does that get over the problem of communicating a failure back to the calling method? Calling "new A()" or "A.getNewInstance()" are equivalent in terms of how expections are communicated aren't they?

Comment: @user53300 Well you could handle exceptions thrown by `new A()` or `a.init()` in the methods and handle them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is thrown in the constructor of an object, it's not much different than finding an exception in a method call, except that you can guarantee your object didn't get constructed

```
NewObject obj = null;
try {
   obj = new NewObject() {
} catch (Throwable t) {
   // obj is null.
}
```

Whether you can recover from such an exception is heavily dependent on the exception thrown.  Checked exceptions are expected, yet infrequent errors; typically they are the easiest to recover from.  Unchecked exceptions deal with things like divide by zero (where having to catch every possible throw would be cumbersome).  Errors are situations where the program is likely to fail due to standard assumptions about normal JVM operation not holding (like the ability to allocate more memory).

It is possible to recover from certain JVM errors; however, the errors you wish to recover from and the means to recover need to be carefully planned.  Typically one sees attempts to recover from JVM errors when dealing with low memory conditions (pseudo-java code follows)

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
while (true) {
  Cache myCache = new SomeCache();
  try {
    Message message = messages.getMessage();
    if (!(cache.hasKey(message))) {
      Result result = messageProcessor.getResult(message);
      cache.put(message, result);
    }
    message.getReplyChannel().send(cache.get(message));
  } catch (OutOfMemoryException e) {
    myCache.clear();
    runtime.gc();
    messages.putBack(message);
  }
}
```

The value of such a solution depends heavily on the rest of the system design.  Assuming the "cache" has a limited maximum size, this might still be useful if another section of the program starts hogging memory.  The key is to make sure your memory freeing operations depend on already allocated objects which will not put more memory demands on the system as it's trying to free memory.

Answer (score -1):

If the entire application is left in a unstable state, I suggest to exit the application directly in order to avoid more problems. Just output something on `system.err` before.

If only the instance will be in a unstable state, you can throw a runtime exception, but I think this is a dangerous way, since their will be no obligation to catch the exception and this can leads to some problems later on.

I suggest to simply rethrow the exception or maybe wrap it in another with other relevant informations. The precise type of the exception will greatly depend on the case (null pointer, illegal state, io error, etc)

Comment: Please don't ever do a `System.exit()` from inside a constructor.  Ever.  First, a constructor should not be qualified to say whether an application will be in an unusable state, and second, even if it did throwing an `Error` is the appropriate way to communicate that cleanly.

Comment: @Mark First of all, you don't give any kind of argument to support your comment. Then, the OP clearly asked what to do if the initialization failure put the application in an unstable state, I'm not here to judge if its constructor is qualified or not to make this decision. By throwing an exception you take the risk that it will be mishandled and the application won't be exited. And finally, I never say to use System.exit(), just to exit the application without specifying the way to do it. And BTW, thanks for the downvote ;)

Comment: Perhaps you could suggest what else "exit the application directly" could mean then.  If some schmuck wants to catch an `Error` (note I didn't say `Exception`) that's his prerogative as a client of your code and he assumes the risk.  It would be no different than catching an `OutOfMemoryError`.  I was trying to say that exiting from a constructor necessarily means that the constructor has way too much control over and insight over the application, which goes against most design principles (coupling, etc). That was my argument and I did add a shorter version to my original comment.